# Failed to exec method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http

Tags: apt, virtualbox

For some reason, when I do `sudo apt-get update` I get this error:

```
sem@sem-VirtualBox:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
Failed to exec method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (100)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
```

This error gets repeated the amount of debs I have in my `sources.list`.

The permissions in `/usr/lib/apt/methods` are ok. The internet connection is ok as well.

This is running in a VirtualBox VM under Windows 8.1.

What I tried so far:

1. Reinstalling `apt-transport-https` through the browser.
2. `software-properties-gtk`
3. Ubuntu Software Center
4. Renewing my `sources.list`
5. Reinstalling Virtualbox Guest Additions
6. `sudo apt-get install -f`
7. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt-transport-https` returns `Reinstallation of apt-transport-https is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.` so apparently my complete `apt` can't connect to the internet. Everything is working in the browser, so I guess I have to reinitialize `apt` itself to get the connection working again?

Comment: are you behind a proxy or something like that?

Comment: I am using a router without a firewall but with forwarded ports, do I need to open a specific port for `apt` to function?

Comment: Removed all forwarding ports and no difference. I get the same error as well when using `software-properties-gtk` or the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Also found out that aptitude wasn't installed, now it is. Sadly no difference.

Comment: My mistake, I misread it as `https`, whereas this is plain http that's failing. Can you try `apt-get update --print-uris` and then try to open one of the links in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by removing and reinstalling APT:

1. `sudo apt-get remove apt` You will be asked to type "Yes, do as I say!"
2. After that, download the apt package through your browser [from here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apt)
3. Go to your Downloads folder and type `sudo dpkg -i <filename>.deb`

After that you can use the `apt-get` functions again.